# Why doesn't apache get confused when it finds CLRFs instead of LFs?

Tags: php, git, apache, laravel

I work in a win 10 environment using homestead to develop laravel-based websites. I have autoclrf set to true in git. Also, I work with git on the "windows side" of the setup. It means, that CLRFs are converted to LFs when files are being commited to the repo, and vise-versa, when they are checked out. The issue is, that apache, which resides in ubuntu, serves scripts, which reside in windows. Why doesn't it get confused, when it discovers, that the scripts have windows-style line endings instead of LFs?

Comment: this is not really a programming question and therefore not fit for SO. however, I think simply because itsimply reads the file and pushes the content to the browser without even caring about linebreaks.

Comment: What about the difference would you *expect* to confuse PHP? A line break made of a CRLF is just some whitespace to PHP, as is a line break made of a single LF.

Comment: @MattGibson Thanks for the answer. As I understood, the line-breaks can be safely ignored in regard to PHP parser. In which cases does the distinction between them matter then?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I disagree. The question is about working specifics of PHP parser, which I think, belongs in programming category. Don't you agree?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia it is about how a program works, not about programming in itself.   MattGibson: basically only when you open a linux-created file with a dumb editor inside windows (most smart ones recognize both) or when you read a file with your scripts and look for "\r\n" explicitly when it only has \n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically because PHP in most cases is insensitive to the difference between `LF` and `CR+LF` which makes sense since it uses [the same lexer on Windows and Unix platforms](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l) so it needs to handle both types of files.

A small representative code snippet from the lexer;

```
if (*p == '\n' || (*p == '\r' && (*(p+1) != '\n'))) {                   \
    CG(zend_lineno)++;                                                  \
}
```

As you can see, it handles either `LF` or `CR+LF` in the same code base.